# web browser crashed when scrolling the virtualization grid after adding a new row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo ui v.2013.1.514, however a really terrible bug was encountered when I was using the grid widget.

As u can see, I set the virtual scroll option to 'true', and have a page size of 25. After I add a new row to the grid using addRow function, the web browser will crash every time scrolling down the grid. That was really bad, cause I need the virtualization and I need to add some new records to the grid, too. I paste some test codes below, hope this could do some help.

BTW, I test on your local demo 'virtualization-local-data.html', all the same. Seems the code just run loops in the 'range' function of DataSource widget.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var arrayDataSource = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        arrayDataSource.push({ 
            check: true, 
            ip: "10.1.201.3"
        });
    }

    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
        height: 600,
        dataSource: {
            data: arrayDataSource,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        check: { type: 'boolean' },
                        ip: { type: 'string' }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 25
        },
        columns: ['check', 'ip'],
        editable: false,
        scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        }
    });

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').addRow();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <button id="add">add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

running the same problem, didn't find any workaround in internet, so after digging in kendo sources found workaround that seems to be working, but only with full datasource refresh

so, scenario is next:

- add item to data array
- set `grid.dataSource._skip = 0;`
- refresh `dataSource like grid.dataSource.data(data);`
- refresh scroll like `$("#grid .k-scrollbar-vertical").scrollTop(0);`

I've updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rDPBu/7/

```
<button id="add">addRow - not working</button>
<button id="add-top">add top</button>
<button id="add-bottom">add bottom</button>
<div id="grid"></div>

var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push({
        check: i + 1,
        ip: '10.1.201.3'
    });
}

var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    height: 300,
    dataSource: {
        data: data,
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "check",
                ip: "ip"
            }
        }
    },
   columns: [
               { field: "check" },
               { field: "ip" }
              ],
   editable: true,
     scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        }
}).data('kendoGrid');

var scroller = $("#grid .k-scrollbar-vertical");

$('#add').click(function () {
    grid.addRow();
});

$('#add-top').click(function () {
    data.splice(0,0,{check: 0, ip: '1.1.1.1'});
    grid.dataSource._skip = 0; // fix databind
    grid.dataSource.data(data);
    scroller.scrollTop(0); // should refresh scroll
});

$('#add-bottom').click(function () {
    data.push({check: 999, ip: '9.9.9.9'});
    grid.dataSource._skip = 0; // fix databind
    grid.dataSource.data(data);
    scroller.scrollTop(scroller.prop("scrollHeight")); // should refresh scroll
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build up at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/rDPBu/3/

```
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    height: 300,
    dataSource: {
        data: [
               {check: 1,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 2,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 3,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 4,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 5,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 6,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 7,ip: "10.1.201.3"},
               {check: 8,ip: "10.1.201.3"}
              ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "check",
                ip: "ip"
            }
        }
    },
   columns: [
               { field: "check" },
               { field: "ip" }
              ],
   editable: true,
     scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        }
}).data('kendoGrid');

$('#add').click(function () {
    grid.addRow();
});
```

**EDIT :**

Answer from Kendo support :

Adding new elements to a grid with virtual scrolling enabled is not a supported setup. Please keep in mind that you can always submit it in our feedback forum, so it can be taken into consideration for our future releases.

Comment: No, Bobby. I know that the datasource is a loop. But what I mean is that, after adding a new row to the source array. The 'range' function of DataSource will calculate a wrong endIndex, so it just run recursively find the accurate data range, and the browser crashes in the end.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I miss read the way you are using the datasource variable, sorry. This works for me without break chrome.

Comment: Try adding a new row in the grid, and scroll down the grid, same result...,you could check the error in the dev tools in chrome

Comment: See, it took you only 2 days to convince me :). I will ask the "Kendo people", aka their support. True is that this is failing, I am assuming its not only in Fiddle right ?

Comment: This feature is not supported. See answer from the kendo support in my answer.